# Argument "1": Conversion from "string" to "System.IO.FileInfo" not possible

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# so its possibly a dumb question, sorry for that :D

When I try to use the method `Encrypt("c:\\test\testfile.txt", "testpwd")`

it says:

> Argument "1": Conversion from "string" to "System.IO.FileInfo" not
>   possible.

I don't know why it cant just change it into a `System.IO.FileInfo`. When I do the same with a random password (where I have a method to) it will say that it is impossibele to transform a `System.Random` to a string.
Can anyone tell me why? thank you in advance.
(Sorry for my English)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Project_Hermes
{
    static class Program
    {
        /* private static Random password = new Random();
         public static string RandomString(int length)
         {
             const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
             return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
               .Select(s => s[password.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
         }*/

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()

        {
            string curFile = "c:\\oot26\\encrypd.txt";



            if (File.Exists(curFile))
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());

            } else
            {
                Encrypt(curFile, "password");

                //Console.WriteLine(password);

                Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\oot26");

                File.Create(curFile);

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }

        private const int SaltSize = 8;

        public static void Encrypt(FileInfo targetFile, string password)
        {
            var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize);
            var rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
            rijndael.IV = keyGenerator.GetBytes(rijndael.BlockSize / 8);
            rijndael.Key = keyGenerator.GetBytes(rijndael.KeySize / 8);

            using (var fileStream = targetFile.Create())
            {
                fileStream.Write(keyGenerator.Salt, 0, SaltSize);

                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                }
            }
        }

        /*public static void Decrypt(FileInfo sourceFile, string password)
        {
            var fileStream = sourceFile.OpenRead();
            var salt = new byte[SaltSize];
            fileStream.Read(salt, 0, SaltSize);
            var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
            var rijndael = Rijndael.Create();
            rijndael.IV = keyGenerator.GetBytes(rijndael.BlockSize / 8);
            rijndael.Key = keyGenerator.GetBytes(rijndael.KeySize / 8);
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, rijndael.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
            }*/
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you googled this? Some basic understanding of types would solve this

Comment: Isn't it obvious that `Encrypt` has FileInfo as first argument and you are trying to call it with string value? That's why you are seeing this error.

Comment: I googled now for over an houer and didn't find anything, thanks for responding

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the `Encrypt` method a `string` when it expects a `FileInfo` object. Try this instead:

```
Encrypt(new FileInfo(curFile), "password");
```